# Using dependency injection on a type="" property

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I'm currently in the process of refactoring our backend, and in the process, I've removed the dependency on a ServiceLocator.
But! this has now given me the headache of figuring out how to do dependency injection, when the type that needs injecting, is pulled from Web.config
The current, specific, case is this:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="MyNamespace.MyClaimsAuthenticationManager, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
      <claimsAuthorizationManager type="MyNamespace.MyClaimsAuthorizationManager, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler,System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler,System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration maximumClockSkew="5"></securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

Here the types MyClaimsAuthenticationManager and MyClaimsAuthorizationManager are the ones that needs their dependencies injected.

The project is running under .NET 4.5, and currently using Ninject for the dependency injection part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [can't do DI with the Provider mechanisms](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/27/Providerisnotapattern) in .NET, mainly because of its reliance on the Constrained Construction anti-pattern.

Your best option is to find a better design that doesn't rely on .NET's Provider mechanisms.

If that's impossible, your next-best option is to treat the Provider (in this case `MyClaimsAuthenticationManager` and `MyClaimsAuthorizationManager`) as [Humble Objects](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) that each contain a [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot) that composes the actual object graph that does the work. In other words, you can view those Providers as [Adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) over whatever object graph you need to spin up in order to do the actual work.

In [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG), I cover this approach in more detail in section 7.5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'd have bought your book right away, but it's not available as a Kindle book :o Will have to wait for the snail mail to deliver it then :-)

Comment: Scrap that, found the ebook on Mannings own site. Thanks, and have a great monday